# Git command always asking for password

Tags: git, passwords, gitlab

I have a GitLab installation on my server. I tried to git clone one repository from my computer, and the problem is it always asking for password. When I type here the password of "git" user in Linux, it works well.

I'm using CentOS with GitLab 11.9.8

I tried to remove the password of "git" user, but still asking for password. When I just press enter, it doesn't accept it.

How can I set the GitLab without asking password?

I would like to set this setting on server, because later there will be a lot of users.

Comment: Gitlab provides many different ways to control and grant access to your repositories, so it would depend on your use case. Do you want your project to be [publicly accessible](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/public_access/public_access.html) by anyone? Or do you want to limit access to specific users?

Comment: @DelenaMalan, I tried the git clone command with Private and Public project as well, none of them works.

I would like to grant access everyone who have an access for the specific GitLab repository.

Comment: You might need to tell SSH (on your computer) which SSH key to use for which server. Do this by creating a "config" file in your SSH folder. Here's an example: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1848261

Comment: I set in this way, but still asking for password of Git user of GitLab server. Should I set any password when generate a new SSH key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Edit the ssd_config file:

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Add or modify these lines:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
RSAAuthentication yes
#AuthenticationMethods password
```

Make sure the permission of these ones:

```
chmod 600 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh
chmod 700 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys
```